# How to return an int from Firebase Realtime Database in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

```
int GetInitial(String roomID) {
    final dbRef =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child(roomID).child("initial");
    db.child(roomID).child('initial').once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      print('Data : ${snapshot.value}');
      return int.parse(snapshot.value);
    });
    return 0;
  }
```

I'm trying to return the value of a child in my Firebase Realtime Database JSON tree, but it keeps giving me zero. I cannot access the value directly using once() as the return value is wrong. The output that I get from printing the value to the console is correct however, however it does not return int.parse(snapshot.value).

Answer (score 1):

`once()` is asynchronous, the `then()` method will register callbacks to be called when this future completes. Therefore in your code 0 will always be returned since it is getting executed before the future is finishing.

To solve that, you can use `async/await`:

```
Future<int> GetInitial(String roomID) async {
    final dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child(roomID).child("initial");
    final snapshot = await db.child(roomID).child('initial').once();
    print('Data : ${snapshot.value}');
    return int.parse(snapshot.value);
  }
```

Comment: I changed it to return snapshot.value() since int.parse() does not work on non-string values, and it returns a future<int>, which I am unable to convert to an int

Comment: you need to use futurebuilder widget to get the int value https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html